# Ajax Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I seem to remember in Laravel 4 there was an ajax filter, this would only allow requests via ajax.

Is there any similar middleware for Laravel 5.

I have a route which gets data from my database via ajax, I want to protect this route so no user can go to it and see a json string of data.

Comment: Do you mean `Request::ajax()`? In Laravel 5 you can use the same

Comment: Yeah, I just want the requests to only be ajax.

Comment: You can do the ajax request and then in your controller function something like this: `if(Request::ajax()) { //echo json } else { //redirect };`

Comment: Thanks, what error code would be correct for this?

Comment: In my opinion `403 Forbidden` is suitable, or maybe `405 Method Not Allowed`

Answer (score 37):

You can use a middleware to do that.

`php artisan make:middleware AllowOnlyAjaxRequests`

> app/Http/Middleware/AllowOnlyAjaxRequests.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AllowOnlyAjaxRequests
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!$request->ajax()) {
            // Handle the non-ajax request
            return response('', 405);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Add `'ajax' => \App\Http\Middleware\AllowOnlyAjaxRequests::class,` to your `routeMiddleware` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

Then you can use `ajax` middleware on your routes.