# Should I check for ajax request or not

Tags: ajax, laravel

**AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "{{url('/post/add')}}",
        data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "id": id
        },

        success: function (data) {
          var res = $.parseJSON(data);
          if(res == true)
          {
              alert('hi');
          }
       }
   });
```

**Laravel Controller:** I have checked for the ajax request in the controller.

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        // codes 
        echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
     }
}
```

but, I noticed that I do not require to check for ajax request? And without checking if the ajax request how am i getting the alert?

```
  public function add(Request $request)
    {
            // codes 
            echo json_encode(TRUE);die
    }
```

Comment: If the call is an ajax call use that if statment to return a json response, else return a view , in this case you will be able to use the same function to retrieve json or a view depending on how you call the function

Comment: @Aschraf even without that if statement i'm returning json response and it is running well.

Comment: i know, but what if you have an other view that wants the same data but you are not accessing data using ajax? what you would do? you will check if it's different than ajax then return a view thats what im saying, if you are using this only for ajax then you dont need to add the if statment

Answer (score 1):

The check is simply one additional measure of a valid request.  It is not necessary as you've noticed, but if you'd like to verify that the request is coming via an AJAX request as you'd expect - you may.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$request->ajax()` to determine [if the request is the result of an AJAX call](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ajax). If you're working only with AJAX requests in your method, you can omit this check.

Answer (score 1):

It just depends on you. You can do different things based on if the request is AJAX request or not. For example returning JSON or a normal view.

If you want your routes to be accessed by only AJAX requests maybe you can protect those routes with a middleware. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32268128/1561146) for more information about that.

Comment: even without that if statement i'm returning json response and it is running well.

Comment: @Steve. yes. Is that a problem? Request is a request. Laravel doesn't care. Its upto you to different things if you want.