# Laravel - controller can tell whether request is from web or api route?

Tags: laravel

So basically I want the following in routes web and api which actually go to the same controller but base on whether it's from web or api then it will either return html or json.

So inside this controller is there a way to know which routes the request is from?

Comment: Given answer is pretty solid - however, if instead of api route, you want to check json you can check `$request->ajax()` - I usually setup ajax middlewares for it [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246359/ajax-middleware/32268128)

Answer (score 7):

You could either use check the path starts with api contains:

```
if (starts_with(request()->path(), 'api'))
```

(the above assumes that all of your api routes are prefixed with `api/`)

[Request Path](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#request-path-and-method)

[starts_with()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-starts-with)

or you could use the `wantsJson()` method to check if the request wants JSON to be returned.

```
if (request()->wantsJson())
```

Personally, I wouldn't see any issue with performing both checks. This way the api route will always return json but if for whatever reason the non-api route needed the json it could get it as well:

```
if (request()->wantsJson() || starts_with(request()->path(), 'api'))
```